# Showing $\lVert (I-F)^{-1} \rVert \leq \frac{1}{1-\lVert F \rVert}$

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, matrix-norms

I'm given that a $F$ is square matrix and satisfies $\lVert F \rVert < 1$ for a norm that is submultiplicative.

Given this I'm asked to show that

$\lVert (I-F)^{-1} \rVert \leq \frac{1}{1-\lVert F \rVert}$

And the hint is to use the Neumann expansion which says that given conditions that we have that $(I-F)^{-1}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty F^i$

If I knew $\lVert (I-F)^{-1} \rVert \leq 1$ then this proof would be trivial because I could just multiply the left side by $1 - \lVert F \rVert$ and divide it over and I'd be done but I don't believe I know this is the case.

Comment: Hint: use the triangle inequality for the Neumann series and then the inequality $||AB||\leq ||A|| ||B||$ for each term several times.

Comment: Ahhh then do I call that series a geometric series that's equal to $1/(1-\lVert F \rVert)$ and then I'm done?

Comment: Yes, that is right.